# Check if three numbers can form a Pythagorean triple?

Tags: python

I need a program which will allow three numbers to be inputted and output if they can form a Pythagorean triple (e.g: a^2 + b^2 = c^2 / or / 3^2 + 4^2 = 5^).

I have a solution, but I feel like it's really inefficient and I was wondering if there is a shorter, better solution available?

*My solution so far:*

```
nums = []

for num in range(0,3):
    nums.append(int(input("Enter a number")))

if ((nums[0] ** 2) + (nums[1] ** 2) == (nums[2] ** 2)):
       // Is a pythagorean triple
```

Etc.. etc..

Comment: this is pretty short as it is. I am not sure how much shorter it can be, checking for a triplet is as simple as an if statement, which you have

Comment: You have a  working solution with no real question, and are simply looking to improve your solution. The Code Review stackexchange site might be better suited here. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is your question if any combination of the 3 input numbers can be a triplet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sort `nums`. Then you will have to make only one check:

```
nums.sort()  # now nums[2] is the largest element
if ((nums[0] ** 2) + (nums[1] ** 2) == (nums[2] ** 2)):
    print "It is"  # or whatever
# no more checks needed
```